# How to keep only specific array keys/values in array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I am searching trough for specific values. 
If those values are found I need to extract the indexes with those values ( make new array ) and remove all others.

array_intersect worked fine on php 5.3 , now on 5.4 it complains Notice:  Array to string conversion.

I found that array_intersect has an issue with multidimensional array on 5.4. 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60198

This is $options array I am searching trough

```
Array (

    [index1] => html
    [index2] => html
    [index3] => slide
    [index4] => tab
    [index5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
        )

)
```

code that works on php 5.3.x

```
$lookfor   = array('slide', 'tab');
$found     = array_intersect($options, $lookfor);


print_r($found);


Array
(
    [index3] => slide
    [index4] => tab
)
```

but in 5.4.x  this trows the error mentioned above.

**What would be another way to do this without a loop please.
and without suppressing the error.**

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use the current code? you should be suppressing all errors that would be displayed to the end user any how, and just don't log these.

Comment: while you were typing I edited my post. I dont want to suppress error. would like to find a solution rather than hiding the notice via @

Comment: What's stopping you from just using a loop?

Comment: @Charles, $options array has over 200 options, thus I rather not loop trough all

Comment: Do it.  Then profile your code using xdebug or xhprof.  I assure you that the mere act of looping over an array with 200 elements in it won't even be a drop in the bucket performance-wise.  What do you think `array_intersect` (and `array_filter` below) *does*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect) isn't recursive. The function assumes the array is just one level deep and expects all the array elements to be scalars. When it finds a non-scalar value, i.e. a sub-array, it throws a Notice.

This is vaguely mentioned in the [documentation for `array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

> Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if: (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

One solution I could think of is to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$lookfor = array('html', 'slide');
$found   = array_filter($options, function($item) use ($lookfor) {
    return in_array($item, $lookfor);
});
```

**Note:** This still performs a looping and isn't any better than a simple `foreach`. In fact, it might be slower than a `foreach` if the array is large. I have no idea why you're trying to avoid loops — I personally think it'd be more cleaner if you just use a loop.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/708015)

Another solution I could think of is to remove the sub-arrays before using `array_intersect()`:

```
<?php

$options = array(
    'index1' => 'html',
    'index2' => 'html',
    'index3' => 'slide',
    'index4' => 'tab',
    'index5' => array(123),
);

$lookfor = array('html', 'slide');
$scalars = array_filter($options,function ($item) { return !is_array($item); });
$found = array_intersect ($scalars, $lookfor);

print_r($found);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/708030)

Comment: @Benn: Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: I mentioned above in a comment , the options array has over 200 options. so I was kinda trying to stay away from the loop and one liner just seems cleaner and faster.

Comment: @Benn: Did you read the comment at the end of my answer? A `foreach` is likely to be faster most of the times. With big arrays, the peak memory usage of the `array_*()` functions may be 2.5 times as much as the `foreach` loop.

Comment: hm , never new that.  do you mind  posting a loop example ? if u have time.

Comment: @Benn: A cleaner solution might be to remove the sub-arrays first, *before* using `array_intersect`. [See demo](https://eval.in/138313).

Answer (score 17):

```
$array = [
    'a' => 4,
    's' => 5,
    'd' => 6,
];
$onlyKeys = ['s','d'];

$filteredArray = array_filter($array, function($v) use ($onlyKeys) {
    return in_array($v, $onlyKeys);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

prinr_r($filteredArray); //  ['s' => 5, 'd' => 6]
```

To filter by value, remove ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY from arguments list.

Comment: `function($v)` is misleading as `$v` implies that it refers a value, which it doesn't. It should rather be `function($key)`.

Answer (score 5):

you could use array_filter()

```
$arr = array(
  'index1' => 'html',
  'index2' => 'html',
  'index3' => 'slide',
  'index4' => 'tab',
  'index5' => array(0 => 123),
);

$with = array('html', 'slide');
$res = array_filter($arr, function($val) use ($with) {
    return in_array($val, $with);
});
```

this will rerturn index1, index2 and index3.

edit: just read your comment that your array will hold lots of entries. `array_filter` will of course loop with a condition over them and create a new array.

Comment: nice one. Il see if anyone else comes up with better solution but for now this one works

Comment: Github-style markdown doesn't work here.  You need to use the indent method instead (easily usable by selecting the code and hitting Ctrl+K or using the toolbar button)

Answer (score 0):

You can still enjoy an array intersecting native function and its in-built optimization instead of making (heavier) iterated calls of `in_array()`; you just need to call `array_uintersect()` instead.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qKVsic))

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect($options, $lookfor, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'index1' => 'html',
  'index2' => 'html',
  'index3' => 'slide',
)
```